# codility:peaks: what's wrong with go implementation on performance parts testing?

Tags: algorithm, go

Divide an array into the maximum number of same-sized blocks, each of which should contain an index P such that A[P - 1] < A[P] > A[P + 1].

My Solution: [golang solution](https://app.codility.com/demo/results/training6BNUWY-TZC/)

However partly performance testing fails without reason, anyone can add some suggestion?

```
func Solution(A []int) int {
    peaks := make([]int, 0)
    for i := 1; i < len(A)-1; i++ {
        if A[i] > A[i-1] && A[i] > A[i+1] {
            peaks = append(peaks, i)
        }
    }

    if len(peaks) <= 0 {
        return 0
    }

    maxBlocks := 0

    // we only loop through the possible block sizes which are less than
    // the size of peaks, in other words, we have to ensure at least one
    // peak inside each block 
    for i := 1; i <= len(peaks); i++ {
        // if i is not the divisor of len(A), which means the A is not
        // able to be equally divided, we ignore them;
        if len(A)%i != 0 {
            continue
        }
        // we got the block size
        di := len(A) / i

        peakState := 0
        k := 0

        // this loop is for verifying whether each block has at least one
        // peak by checking the peak is inside A[k]~A[2k]-1
        // if current peak is not valid, we step down the next peak until
        // valid, then we move to the next block for finding valid peak;

        // once all the peaks are consumed, we can verify whether all the
        // blocks are valid with peak inside by checking the k value, 
        // if k reaches the 
        // final state, we can make sure that this solution is acceptable
        for {
            if peakState > len(peaks)-1 {
                break
            }
            if k >= i {
                break
            }
            if peaks[peakState] >= di*k && peaks[peakState] <= di*(k+1)-1 {
                peakState++
            } else {
                k++
            }
        }
        // if all peaks are checked truly inside the block, we can make
        // sure this divide solution is acceptable and record it in the
        // global max block size
        if k == i-1 && peakState == len(peaks) {
            maxBlocks = i
        }

    }
    return maxBlocks
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain in words the logic of the `for i := 1; i <= len(peaks)...` loop with the nested for loop inside?

Comment: @גלעדברקן the explanation was added inside code

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for adding more comments to your code. The idea seems to make sense. If the judge is reporting a wrong answer, I would try it with random data and some edge cases and a brute-force control to see if you can catch a failing example that's reasonably sized, and analyse what is wrong.

My own thought about a possible approach so far was to record a prefix array so as to tell in `O(1)` if a block has a peak. Add 1 if the element is a peak, 0 otherwise. For input,

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2
```

we would have:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2
0  0  0  1  1  2  2  2  2  2  3  3
```

now when we divide, we know if a block contains a peak if its relative sum is positive:

```
  1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2
0|0  0  0  1| 1  2  2  2| 2  2  3  3
a          b           c           d
```

If the first block did not contain a peak, we would expect `b - a` to equal 0 but instead we get 1, meaning there's a peak. This method would guarantee `O(num blocks)` for each divisor test.

The second thing I would try is to iterate from the smallest divisor (largest block size) to the largest divisor (smallest block size), but skip divisors that can be divided by a smaller divisor that failed validation. For example, if 2 succeeded but 3 failed, there's no way 6 can succeed, but 4 still could.

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
2          |
3      |       |
6  |   |   |   |    |
4 x  |x    |    x|    x
```